# ajax loading of search results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have setup a search funtionality that will search in an XSLT file. This works flawlessly but I have a little trouble returning the search results dynamically with ajax.

This is my JS:

```
 var SearchHandler = function(frm) {

        frm = $(frm);
        var data = frm.find(".search-field").val();

        $.ajax({ 
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/',
            data: { query: data },
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: SearchSuccessHandler,
            error: SearchSuccessHandler
        });

    };

    var SearchSuccessHandler = function(html) {


    };
```

What I want is the SearchSuccessHandler to dynamically load the search result from index.php?query=searchword

I just can't seem to figure out the right way to handle it.

Comment: Dynamically load the results where? How?

Comment: Bah.. Sorry... The ajax call will return some new html based on the query ... I want the existing html to be replaced

I have tried $('body').html(html.responseText); but then I cannot search again because javascript is not loaded correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> Bah.. Sorry... The ajax call will return some new html based on the
>   query ... I want the existing html to be replaced I have tried
>   *`$('body').html(html.responseText);`* but then I cannot search again
>   because javascript is not loaded correctly

It's not the AJAX which is the issue but rather *event delegation*

When you bind a function to an element directly like this:

`$('.my-element').on('whatever', function() { ... })`

the handler will work as long as the element exists **however** if you *replace* the contents of the *entire body* you'll run into trouble as your **original** `.my-element` no longer exists.

You can overcome that by using event delegation to make sure your function keeps searching e.g.

`$(body).on('whatever', '.my-element', function() { ... })`

This basically says: "If I click on body and the *target* is `.my-element` then execute this function"
Instead of a directly bound handler which says: "If I click **on this specific element** then execute this function"

the `body` will always exist and therefore you'll always be able to delegate down from the body but if you can do it on some more specific element that would obviously be better since then you won't have an `onclick` handler on the entire body.

I think this is what your issue is since you're replacing the entire body.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
success:function(data) {
// do your stuff here
}
```

Of course, you need to be sure your function is returning some values. 
To make it easier for your, encode the values as json on your index.php

```
return json_encode($values)
```

Then, inside your success function, just parse it with eval()